# how to fix module not found error in vs code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm-install

I'm new to node.js.
When I am trying to install `npm` module in VSCode, it is throwing an error `MODULE NOT FOUND`.

I've tried `npm install readline-sync` multiple times but the result was same.

Thanks

Comment: could you please post the full error